# Gradle : Run subproject's tasks in parallel

Tags: parallel-processing, gradle, task, subproject

My project structure is look like

```
Root + subproj1
     + subproj2
```

in each sub project defined his own task run(){}.
What i'm trying to do is run :subproj1:run, :subproj2:run in parallel from Root project's run task.
I tried in root project's build.gradle

```
task run(){
  def threads = 2
  def tasks = [ ":subproj1:run", ":subproj2:run" ]
  tasks.each {
    new Thread(){
      public void run(){
        dependsOn it
      }
    }.start();
  }
}
```

but it makes an exception like

```
Exception in thread "Thread-12" org.gradle.api.UnknownProjectException:
Project with path ':subproj1:run' could not be found in root project 'ROOT'
```

How i can run sub project's task in parallel from root project?

Comment: Why can't you just call `Thread.start`?  Why do you need `new Thread() ... public void run() ...`.

Answer (score 3):

With gradle 2.1 it should work out of the box. One solution is --parallel like Perryn said or you set org.gradle.parallel:true into your gradle.properties. And then you should be able to run "gradle run" in the root project and both should be executed parallel.

I also put undeclared-project-coupling=fail into gradle.properties to know if they are coupled and can't be executed in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried looking at the --parallel command line option?